# Login screen issue with C# webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, authentication, connection

I try to code a website with webservice in it.
My login page code is:

```
 protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DBKariyerBL.User user = new DBKariyerBL.User();
        user.UserName = txtKlnAd.Text;
        user.Password = txtParola.Text;
        if (user.Login(user))
        {
            Session["LogIn"] = "1";
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
    }
```

and my User.cs page in business layer is:

```
public class User
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Util.ConnectionString);

        public bool Login(User user)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(conn, CommandType.Text, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE UserName=@UserName AND Password=@Password", new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@UserName", user.UserName), new SqlParameter("@Password", user.Password) })) > 0;
        }


    }
```

My User.asmx page is like:

```
public class User : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public bool Login(DBKariyerBL.User user)
    {
        DBKariyerBL.User kull = new DBKariyerBL.User();
        return kull.Login(user);
    }
}
```

and I have a Util.cs for SQL connection:

```
public class Util
{

    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection"].ConnectionString; }
    }
}
```

When I run this project in my local server, is working fine, but when I try to put this code in my test server, it gives an error page:

> Cannot open database "DenizBankKariyerDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DenizKariyer'.

I'm stuck. I think the problem is in my Util.cs file.

Comment: can you show me your connection string ?

Comment: in webconfig file of webservices, this connection string code is in:
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DenizBankKariyerDB;Integrated Security=True;" />
  </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear: the login provided in the connection string for the database you're trying to connect to is not valid. The user does not exist, or they don't have rights applied to the catalog, or the password is incorrect, etc.

The way to solve this is to check your database, confirm the user details, and apply them in the connection string accordingly.

Comment: i checked my DB, there is only user for IIS APPPOOL\Service

Answer (score 0):

since you added integrated security = true the sql server uses the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.What you want is to use is the username and password from the forms .

So instead of using the connection string from the config try to use the something like this.

```
public class Util
  {

public static string ConnectionString
{
    get { return  "Data Source=ServerName;" +
"Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;" +
"User id=UserName;" +
"Password=pwd;"; }
}
}
```

you can have a method that takes server, username ,password as parameters.